# SubGroup Discovery on unseen data

Tags: data-mining, association-rules

The technique of subgroup discovery in data mining is known for using Minimum Description Length (MDL) and Rule-Based Induction to calculate the complexity of a learner and divide a dataset into multiple subsets. These subsets are ideally saturated, containing all the information needed to derive the target. In particular, the calculation of CLCH (the Complexity of the Least Complex correct Hypothesis) is used. There are many variations of this technique, but all have the main goal of describing the structure of the data comprehensibly. However, it may be necessary to make inferences with new data to obtain accurate predictions for the future.

Regarding this, the bibliography is very scarce. How can I insert new data into a subgroup discovery system? To which subset of data does it belong? The technique of associating with the nearest input does not seem to yield good results because it does not capture non-linear relationships, and a noise component can associate the data with the wrong subset. Do you have any ideas on this or any articles or books that I may have missed? Please consider that we do not know the target for the new data.

Thank you.

Comment: And if, after performing the subdivision into subgroups, I applied another learner like KNN, could I then use Euclidean distance with good results?